# sqlplus output header wrongly formatted and un-necessary blank lines

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm new to SQL, I'm trying to run a query to extract alarms from DB using certain conditions and output the result to a file in csv format.

I created the below SQL script however the header is not generated in the required format.

```
set markup HTML on ENTMAP on spool off PREFORMAT on;
set pagesize 0 embedded on;
set feedback off;
set termout off;
set trimout on;
spool on;
set trimspool on;
spool /tmp/scripts/outputFiles/calExport.csv REPLACE;
select (y.ALARM_DN||','||x.CO_NAME||','||to_char(y.ALARM_TIME, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')||','||y.ALARM_TEXT||','||y.ALARM_TYPE||','||y.PERCEIVED_SEVERITY||','||y.ADDITIONAL_INFO_1||','||y.ADDITIONAL_INFO_3||','||y.ADDITIONAL_INFO_2) from CTP_COMMON_OBJECTS x, FM_ALARM y where y.NE_GID=x.CO_GID and y.ALARM_STATUS=1;
spool off;
exit;
```

Current output:
'

```
'
(Y.ALARM_DN||','||X.CO_NAME||','||TO_CHAR(Y.ALARM_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')||
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxxx/xxxx-143/xxxx-143,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
,03-10-2017 15:19:49,Dead Peer Detected,1,2,shared:N;,,additionalFaultId:0;
```

xxxx/xxxx-143/xxxx-143,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,13-09-
2017 12:45:48,LOS on unit 0, Ethernet interface 4,1,1,,,

xxxx/xxxx-143/xxxx-143,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,03-10-2017 15:19:39,BA
NOTIFICATION,3,3,Files collected,,100 100 100 6450xxxx 1 0
 path=/xxxx-1(Left) additionalFaultId:6450;

Problems:

1. How to correct header format to match with below?

   ```
   ALARM_DN,NAME,ALARM_TIME,TEXT,TYPE,SEVERITY,A,B,C
   ```
2. How to remove "pre" tag at the beginning and end of the output file?
3. How to remove the blank lines after each row in the output? I used set trimspool on but blank lines are still there.

Appreciate your help.

BR,

A.M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the heading to what you want change your SQL*Plus script to:

```
set markup HTML on ENTMAP on spool off PREFORMAT on;
set pagesize 0 embedded on;
set feedback off;
set termout off;
set trimout on;
SET HEADING OFF;
spool on;
set trimspool on;
spool /tmp/scripts/outputFiles/calExport.csv REPLACE;
SELECT 'ALARM_DN,NAME,ALARM_TIME,TEXT,TYPE,SEVERITY,A,B,C' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
select (y.ALARM_DN||','||x.CO_NAME||','||to_char(y.ALARM_TIME, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')||','||y.ALARM_TEXT||','||y.ALARM_TYPE||','||y.PERCEIVED_SEVERITY||','||y.ADDITIONAL_INFO_1||','||y.ADDITIONAL_INFO_3||','||y.ADDITIONAL_INFO_2) from CTP_COMMON_OBJECTS x, FM_ALARM y where y.NE_GID=x.CO_GID and y.ALARM_STATUS=1;
spool off;
exit;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob, that solved the header issue. For the blank lines, i managed to solve it using following `set wrap off` and `set linesize xxxx` commands. Any ideas how to remove the <pre> tag from the beginning and end of the file? Also, in one column i have a result that already include "," so when spooling to csv this cell is wrongly split due to this comma sign...how can I overcome this?

Comment: On the `<pre>` tags, this is purely a guess but you might change the first line of the file to say `PREFORMAT OFF`. If your data already includes commas then you can either use another character to break the fields - I've used `|` (vertical bar) in the past because it's relatively uncommon - or replace the commas in your data with blanks using the `REPLACE` function. Best of luck.